# Argument problem complex

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have been given that $\frac{\pi}{2}< arg(z-i)< \frac{3\pi}{2}$
and that $z_1=1/z$, how do I find $arg(z_1)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that the argument of a complex number is within the bounds $(\pi/2,\ 3\pi/2)$ is the same as saying it has a negative real part. Hence$\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}} \renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
$$ \Re(z-i) < 0 $$
But adding a purely imaginary number to a complex number won't alter its real part, so
\begin{align}
\Re(z-i+i) = \Re(z) < 0
\end{align}
We can now compute the argument of $z$ by using arctangent:
\begin{align}
\arg(z) &= \pi + \arctan\left(\frac{\Im z}{\Re z} \right)
\end{align}
with $\pi$ added since $\Re(z) < 0$. The argument of $1/z$ is simply the negation:
\begin{align}
\arg(1/z) &= -\pi - \arctan\left(\frac{\Im z}{\Re z} \right)
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{re^{\theta i}} &= \frac{1}{r} \left(e^{\theta i} \right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{r} e^{-\theta i}
\end{align}
Because the range of arctangent is $(-\pi/2,\ \pi/2)$, the expression we obtained for $\arg(1/z)$ will be in the range $(-3\pi/2,\ -\pi/2)$. Since you originally state that $\pi/2 < \arg(z-i) < 3\pi/2$ this is probably the wrong range to use. If we add $2\pi$ to our expression for $\arg(1/z)$, we get
\begin{align}
\arg(1/z) &= \pi - \arctan\left(\frac{\Im z}{\Re z} \right)
\end{align}
which will be in the more appropriate range $(\pi/2,\ 3\pi/2)$.